# Google test's `TestWithParam` alternative in Google benchmark?

Tags: c++, googletest, google-benchmark

In google test, people can use `TestWithParam` for customized parameter in a fixture. That is to say, write a class that inheritates `testing::TestWithParam<Customed_Params>` class, in which `Customed_Params` is my own defined class that holds customed parameters, such as the mixture of ints and strings.

However in google benchmark library (the performance testsing library), there isn't `TestWithParam`. There is `Args()` member function for the `Benchmark` class, but it only accept `int64_t` type parameters, and my `std::string` type parameter can't be passed.

i.e.

```cpp
BENCHMARK_REGISTER_F(AreaResizeFast_Fixture, cv)
    ->Unit(benchmark::kMillisecond)
    ->UseRealTime()
    ->Args({"1.jpg", 2, 2})  // the 1.jpg can't be passed
    ->Args({"2.jpg", 3, 3}); // the 2.jpg can't be passed
```